# Rotatable Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

we have an app with locked layout. As far as I know dialog inherits orientation from the parent Activity. Most of out controls are images so it is very easy to rotate them based on the device orientation. We use a selection dialog to change some app parameters. It would be good if we also could rotate it. Any ideas?
Transparent activity will not work as it will also unlock the main activity orientation.
Thanks.

Comment: Your Dialog can inherit from `DialogFragment` to handle orientation changes

Comment: Hi Juan, How do I do that? How do I handle the orientation changes if the main activity orientation is locked? That is the question I've been trying to find the answer for. :)